# Как можно не перперерендерить vue шаблон при открытии страницы?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

Есть страница сайта сделанная на vue. Но с vue страница рендерится на клиенте и изначально страница прходит пустой. Это не подходит для seo т.к. яндекс такие динамические страницы не воспринимает. По этому решено было на php сервере, заполнять страницу php шаблоном, который потом, на клиенте, подменится на шаблон из vue. Шаблоны в php и vue идентичны(по крайнейме я стараюсь что бы так было). Проблема в том, что при подключениии, vue перерендеривает всю страницу шаблона, и страница в этот момент маргает.

**Можно ли как то объяснить vue, что бы он не перерисовывал шаблон при поделючении на страницу?**

**Т.е. как-то указать, что это начальный DOM, соответствует тому, который указан в шаблоне компоненты и изначально пререндеривать его не нужно?**

*Варианты с nuxt и серверсайт рендерингом и пререндерингом и т.д. не подходит, сейчас нужен временный вариант без nodejs на php, какое нибудь временное решение*

*Я смотрел в nuxt страница не перерендеривается при подключениие vue, там передаётся в шаблон параметр. Я пытался сделать тоже самое в обычном шаблоне отданым php, но это почему то не работает. Из-за чего так может быть? Может мне в эту сторону копать?*

Comment: Такое сделать нельзя. Придумывайте что-нибудь другое.

Comment: Хотя, с другой стороны, VUE-SSR, это же как-то делает. Кстати, для PHP - это делает Laravell, кажись

Comment: `Шаблоны в php и vue идентичны` там и там vue директивы используете, такие как `v-for`?

Comment: @Дмытрык `SSR` в принципе не возможен штатными средствами, т.к. там `JS`. @vvtvvtvvt1 есть только одно нормально и оптимальное решение: `V8Js`.

Comment: @Дмытрык, да, вот пытаюсь понять, как это делается в vue-ssr, что бы сделать примерно тоже самое на php.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, нет, не используются. Я имел ввиду, что сервер на php возвращает DOM такой же как должен рендерится с vue.

Comment: Вы бы код привели, чтобы стал ясен механизм реализации: `при подключениии, vue перерендеривает всю страницу шаблона, и страница в этот момент маргает.` Vue же не может сам уничтожить DOM и подставить свои шаблоны. Помимо ssr есть еще такой [механизм](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/vue-js-tutorial-a-prerendered-seo-friendly-example-live-demo-771e974e909c/)

Comment: @РустамГимранов . Как такового механизма нет. к сожалению, и речь фактически лишь об одном шаблоне - страница товара, по этому вместо межанизма тупо руки. Скопировал из браузера сегенерированную vue размертку одной из страниц и подставил туда конструкции из php что бы подставлять нужные данные.  'Vue же не может сам уничтожить DOM' - почему? Когда vue монитруется к элементу она заменяет его содержимое,   на дерево сгенерированное на основе шаблона во vue. А так как я её монтирую к корневому элементу, то фактически перерендеривается вся страница.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, перерендеринг не подходит т.к. много страниц генерить надо т.к. много товаров. Вообще пларинуется делать ssr, но сроки горят, и хочется сейчас хоть какое нибудь временное решение найти.